# GROUP BY statement HiveQL

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm a noobie to Hive. My question is why we need to use collect_set(col) while performing GROUP BY?

select singer, collect_set(song) from songlist GROUP BY singer;;

would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude!! It is the other way around :)

All Summation/aggregation things need a group by. 
In your query, while you are trying to do a collect_set(col) you require a group by for it.

So In your case you are trying to group all songs sung by a singer. Hence the group by for the collect_set(songs)

Comment: Thanks for your response Partha! I have another couple question :) what is the difference between the two statements. Select singer, songs from songslist GROUP BY singer; and select singer, collect_set(songs) from songslist GROUPBY singer; Also why the first statement results in error.

Comment: Select singer, songs from songslist GROUP BY singer; 

Yes obviously, this is erroneous. 

a. All columns in select needs to be in group by statement. So in your case you need songs column in group by as well. 
Moreover, if you frame that query like this the output will be distinct of singers and songs and not the result same as collect_set query.